# How to use proxy during build time in podman

Tags: dockerfile, podman, podman-compose

I want to build my image using custom `Dockerfile`. It should be connected to a proxy to download some files. I there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bash ENV `http_proxy`

Based on [this link](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-set-proxy-settings-on-linux-command-line-or-terminal/) the best way is to using bash environment proxies!

You can use the bash `env` proxies!

```
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8088 https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8088
```

It even supports `socks5` protocol:

```
export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8088 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8088
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the official documentation to see that the `build` command has a `--env` option：

> --env=env[=value]
>
> Add a value (e.g. env=value) to the built image. Can be used multiple times. If neither = nor a value are specified, but env is set in the current environment, the value from the current environment is added to the image. To remove an environment variable from the built image, use the --unsetenv option.

More details can read from [podman-build -- Podman documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html#env-env-value)

For example, I has a proxy server like `http://192.168.1.100:7890` and a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM archlinux
RUN env
RUN pacman -Syy && pacman -S zsh --noconfirm
WORKDIR /root
```

Then I can build this Dockerfile by command:

```bash
podman build -t zsh --env=http_proxy=http://192.168.1.100:7890 \
 --env=https_proxy=http://192.168.1.100:7890 .
```

The standard output will print this:

```bash
STEP 1/6: FROM archlinux
STEP 2/6: ENV "http_proxy"="http://192.168.1.100:7890" "https_proxy"="http://192.168.1.100:7890"
--> a3770a5a3024
STEP 3/6: RUN env
HOSTNAME=dbb3f7228c20
PWD=/
HOME=/root
LANG=C.UTF-8
https_proxy=http://192.168.110.126:7890
SHLVL=0
http_proxy=http://192.168.110.126:7890
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/sbin/env
--> 567a15dd2af3
STEP 4/6: RUN pacman -Syy && pacman -S zsh --noconfirm
:: Synchronizing package databases...
```